# Displaying image instead of source - bootstrap multi-select plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5b39tatu/)

I am using [bootstrap multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) to generate dropdown with checkboxes with image for each checkbox.

I have used optionLabel to add image before checkbox, but it displays code instead of displaying the image, I've been trying hour trying to figure out, any help would be appreciated.

**html**

```
<select id="example-multiple-selected" multiple="multiple" style="display: none;">
    <option value="option-1" data-img="bigstock1.png">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2" data-img="bigstock2.png">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option-3" data-img="bigstock3.png">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option-4" data-img="bigstock4.png">Option 4</option>
    <option value="option-5" data-img="bigstock5.png">Option 5</option>
    <option value="option-6" data-img="bigstock6.png">Option 6</option>
</select>
```

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example-multiple-selected').multiselect({
        optionLabel: function(element) {
            return '<img src="http://placehold.it/' + $(element).attr('data-img') + '"> ' + $(element).text();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `enableHTML` option, Go through [Configuration Options](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options) for more info.

```
$('.multiselect').multiselect({
    enableHTML: true,
    optionLabel: function(element) {
        return '<img src="http://placehold.it/'+$(element).attr('data-img')+'"> '+$(element).text();
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/ohk5mgne/)

Answer (score 1):

just change your code to this,

```
$('#example-multiple-selected').multiselect({
        enableHTML: true,
        optionLabel: function(element) {
        return ' '+$(element).text();
    }
});
```